# What's the purpose of @ in this c# code?

Tags: c#

I have seen a sample C# code that looked like this:

```
private static string GetCommandLine(Process process)
{
    string cmd = "";
    using (var s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + process.Id))
    {
        foreach (var @object in s.Get())
        {
            if (cmd.Length > 0) cmd += " ";
            cmd += @object["CommandLine"];
        }
    }
    return cmd;
}
```

What is the purpose of the @ in the loop variable?

Comment: `object` is a keyword in C#. Variables can not have same name as keywords. You need use `@` prefix to if you want to use keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use reserved words as variable names, you prefix them with the @ sign.

Comment: It never occurred to me that it was part of the variable name. I though it was an operator :-)